# Why is Rails not precompiling javascripts and stylesheets inside the vendor directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my project I have third party JavaScripts and Css files inside the `vendor/assets/javascripts` and `vendor/assets/stylesheets` directories. In development mode I can refer to the assets within those directories using the `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_include_tag` methods.

However those scripts do not get precompiled when I run the `rake assets:precompile` command and subsequently can't be accessed in production.

Could someone please say why are assets inside the `vendor` directory get ignored by the rake task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question.

This wasn't obvious to me but it does make sense. Except for the `application.css` and `application.js` file all other .js/.css files get ignored by the precompile rake task. Therefore as long as your scripts and stylesheets are referenced using `//= require name_of_script` convention inside the `application.js/.css` files they will get appended to the relavant file fine.

However if you don't want certain scripts to be placed inside the `application.js/.css` files, then you need to explicitly tell Rails that you still want them to be precompiled using this line inside the `config/environment/production.rb` or other relavant runtime environment config file:

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
config.assets.precompile += %w( morris.min.js raphael.min.js )
```